# Django Formset Missing Management Form Data

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I'm attempting to write unit tests for a formset, but I'm getting the following error when trying to instantiate it.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/jwelborn/Documents/projects/Bingo/bingo/cards/tests/test_forms.py", line 218, in test_formset_accepts_valid_data
        self.assertTrue(formset.is_valid())
    File "/home/jwelborn/Documents/projects/Bingo/bingoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 321, in is_valid
        self.errors
    File "/home/jwelborn/Documents/projects/Bingo/bingoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 295, in errors
        self.full_clean()
    File "/home/jwelborn/Documents/projects/Bingo/bingoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 343, in full_clean
        for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):
    File "/home/jwelborn/Documents/projects/Bingo/bingoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 116, in total_form_count
        return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)
    File "/home/jwelborn/Documents/projects/Bingo/bingoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "/home/jwelborn/Documents/projects/Bingo/bingoenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 98, in management_form
        code='missing_management_form',
    django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

This error says I'm missing ManagmentForm data, but I include it in the dictionary I'm passing to my form. I've checked different spellings and varying the min and max numbers, to no avail.

forms.py:

```
class BingoSquareForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BingoCardSquare
        exclude = ('created_date',)


BingoSquareFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    BingoCard,
    BingoCardSquare,
    form=BingoSquareForm,
    min_num=24,
    validate_min=True,
    max_num=24,
    validate_max=True
)
```

tests.py

```
class BingoSquareFormsetTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.user = User.objects.get_or_create(
            username='FormsetTestUser',
            email='something@yahoo.org'
        )[0]
        self.user.set_password('bingo')
        self.user.save()

        self.card = BingoCard.objects.get_or_create(
            title='FormsetTest',
            free_space='free_space',
            creator=self.user,
        )[0]

        self.data = {
            'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '24',
            'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
            'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '24',
            'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': '24'
        }

        for i in range(24):
            text_key = 'form-{}-text'.format(i)
            text_value = 'square {}'.format(i)
            self.data[text_key] = text_value

    def test_formset_accepts_valid_data(self):

        formset = BingoSquareFormset(self.data)
        self.assertTrue(formset.is_valid())
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error was caused by not using the proper prefix for the formset's form data. Django's `inlineformset_factory` automatically sets the formset prefix to the `related_name` defined in the ForeignKeyField on the child model.

models.py:

```
class BingoCardSquare(models.Model):

    ...

    card = models.ForeignKey(
        BingoCard,
        related_name='squares',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    ...
```

In this instance, the `self.data` attribute should have been set to the following:

```
self.data = {
    'squares-TOTAL_FORMS': '24',
    'squares-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
    'squares-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '24',
    'squares-MIN_NUM_FORMS': '24'
    }
```

Each additional form would need to be prefixed the same way. Hopefully this answer will help a future djangonaut in distress.

Comment: Also see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets): "`BookFormSet`’s prefix is `'book_set'` (`<model name>_set` ). If `Book`’s `ForeignKey` to `Author` has a `related_name`, that’s used instead." This refers to `BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(parent_model=Author, model=Book, ...)`).

Comment: Thanks @djvg but those docs didn't exist when I asked this question. I added them ;)

https://github.com/django/django/pull/9320/files#diff-b770e22689c131252859d05dd4d3cb1724717d241b6953a7fb8290b7418da1edR1151

Comment: Right, I see. Thanks for that! :-D